# Setting up triple integral with order $\int_x\int_z\int_y dy dz dx$ and $y=4-x^2-4z^2$ and $ y = 0$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I was able to find the x and y bounds, $\int^2_{-2}\int_z\int_0^{4-x^2-4z^2} dy dz dx$, but I'm having trouble with z. Manipulating the y equation with y set to zero I got $4-x^2=4z^2->\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{4}}= z^2$ but they have (+/-)$\sqrt{4-x^2}/2$ and I'm not sure how they worked it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First take the plus and minus square root, then  divide by $2$.$$4z^2=4-x^2\implies 2z = \pm \sqrt{4-x^2}\implies z=\pm \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{4-x^2}$$

Comment: Hm Ok guess you can do that. For some reason I was looking at it like.. I don't know. My brain is being stupid right now. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. It has happened to everyone on several occasions (hint: don't look at my questions). Best of luck!